# Find normal based on rotation?

Tags: mathematics, blender

Given the XYZ rotation of an object, e.g. `(90,0,0)`, how can I find the object's normal assuming the object is pointing along it's local Z axis?

In the above example the desired result is `(0,1,0)`.

---

<sub>I'm using blender, but this seemed like more of a general math question so I decided to ask here..</sub>

Comment: You'll need to convert the XYZ rotation (Euler angles) to a quaternion or matrix, and apply it to `(0, 0, 1)` to convert that from local to world space.  You can find plenty of information on converting Euler angles to other forms of rotation, and applying rotations to vectors, with a bit of googling.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the object's Normal as vector (X,Y,Z). I guess that will be (0,0,1) in your case.
2. Construct rotation matrix from your angles (e.g. [euler-to-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996957/conversion-euler-to-matrix-and-matrix-to-euler) or any other "Euler to Matrix" instructions that suit you). Order of rotations is important.
3. Multiply your Normal with Rotation matrix